# Have Monitoring Program on Standard User Account with Admin rights

Tags: admin, parental-control

I'm not sure if this website is for these kinds of questions, if not I'm Sorry.
I have looked everywhere but nothing seems to fit my situation.
Basically I have a Computer, with a younger Sister who gets onto a Non admin account to do school work during the day, and afterwards when her work is done, she can play a game. I understand i can block the game to where i have to type in a password to give her the ability to start it. I want to add automation to this as well as other functions to monitor her activity. i have some ideas for macros to set up using a program i love called EventGhost.

So getting to the point, i want this program to start when she logs on, and i want it to start in the background with admin rights to change and do stuff behind the scenes, but I don't want her to be able to see or access it. I have already blocked her permissions to use Eventghost and her access to the task manager. but now i need it to start up above her access. I already tried to put it in the windows startup folder and set the shortcut to launch as admin, but have had no luck.

Does anyone know if its even possible? I remember in school there was a Program that ran in the task bar that allowed the teachers to see your screen, as a student user you could not stop it or access it. If its not possible any alternative to being able to set the game to being accessible through a wireless app or something would work. Hopefully this makes sense... Thanks

Comment: What is Acct mentioned in the title?

Comment: I meant account , fixed